# Comunicação Bidirecional - Enviar e Receber valor em string de forma correta

Tags: c#, socket, tcpclient

Segue código do ***servidor***:

```
int port = 11000/*PortGranter.GrantPort()*/;
TcpSocketListener listener = new TcpSocketListener();
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<ITcpSocketClient>();

await listener.StartListeningAsync(port);
listener.ConnectionReceived += (sender, args) => tcs.SetResult(args.SocketClient);

var socket2 = await tcs.Task;
await listener.StopListeningAsync();

// for five seconds, send and receive the data 
var sentToSocket1 = new List<byte>();
var sentToSocket2 = new List<byte>();
var recvdBySocket1 = new List<byte>();
var recvdBySocket2 = new List<byte>();

// send random data and keep track of it
// also keep track of what is received
Func<ITcpSocketClient, List<byte>, List<byte>, CancellationToken, Task> sendAndReceive =
    (socket, sent, recvd, token) =>
    {
        var r = new Random(socket.GetHashCode());
        var send = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            var buf = new byte[1000];
            while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                //r.NextBytes(buf);
                //sent.AddRange(buf);
                //await socket.WriteStream.WriteAsync(buf, 0, buf.Length, token);
                //await socket.WriteStream.FlushAsync(token);

                Byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"Amanhã não vou para escola, porque eu estou doente.<OAF>");
                await socket.WriteStream.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length, token);
                await socket.WriteStream.FlushAsync(token);
            }
        });

        var recv = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            var buf = new byte[1000];
            while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                var len = await socket.ReadStream.ReadAsync(buf, 0, buf.Length, token);
                recvd.AddRange(buf.Take(len));
            }
        });

        var innerTcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        token.Register(() => innerTcs.SetResult(true));

        return innerTcs.Task;
    };
```

Segue código do ***cliente***:

```
int port = 11000/*PortGranter.GrantPort()*/;
TcpSocketClient socket1 = new TcpSocketClient();
await socket1.ConnectAsync("192.168.0.153", port);

var sentToSocket1 = new List<byte>();
var sentToSocket2 = new List<byte>();
var recvdBySocket1 = new List<byte>();
var recvdBySocket2 = new List<byte>();

//enviar dados aleatórios e acompanhar isso também acompanhar o que é recebido
Func<ITcpSocketClient, List<byte>, List<byte>, CancellationToken, Task> sendAndReceive =
    (socket, sent, recvd, token) =>
    {
        var r = new Random(socket.GetHashCode());
        var send = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            var buf = new byte[1000];
            while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                r.NextBytes(buf);
                sent.AddRange(buf);
                await socket.WriteStream.WriteAsync(buf, 0, buf.Length, token);
                await socket.WriteStream.FlushAsync(token);
            }
        });

        var recv = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            var buf = new byte[1];
            while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                var len = await socket.ReadStream.ReadAsync(buf, 0, buf.Length, token);
                recvd.AddRange(buf.Take(len));
            }
        });

        var innerTcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        token.Register(() => innerTcs.SetResult(true));

        return innerTcs.Task;
    };

string result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(recvdBySocket1.ToArray());
```

Na variável `result` retorna várias vezes o texto `Amanhã não vou para escola, porque eu estou doente.<OAF>`.

Exemplo de como ele retorna:

`Amanhã não vou para escola, porque eu estou doente.<OAF>Amanhã não vou para escola, porque eu estou doente.<OAF>Amanhã não vou para escola, porque eu estou doente.<OAF>Amanhã não vou para escola, porque eu estou doente.<OAF>Amanhã não vou para escola, porque eu estou doente.<OAF>...`

A biblioteca que eu uso: https://github.com/rdavisau/sockets-for-pcl

Aqui tem código completo parecido com a minha: https://github.com/rdavisau/sockets-for-pcl/blob/dev/Sockets/Tests/Sockets.Tests/TcpSocketClientTests.cs#L166

**Eu apenas quero fazer algo assim:**

*Cliente manda valor para servidor depois servidor mandar para cliente e FIM.*

Foi único exemplo que eu achei na internet de como fazer comunicação bidirecional usando PCL (*Portable Class Libraries*).

Alguma solução ?

Comment: Não são os limites de buffer que você está usando?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo Mais o buffer não seria enviar parte por parte até finalizar ?

Comment: Enquanto você não recebe o token.IsCancellationRequested você lê o buffer de 0 até o seu tamanho

Comment: Matheus nao sei se voce entedeu certo. O Leandro chamou atencao para o laco com `IsCancellationRequested `. Enquanto voce nao fizer um cancelamento o servidor vai continuar a enviar a mensagem. Já agora esse exmeplo é horrivel...

Comment: @BrunoCosta, se você pudesse mostrar um exemplo mais simples, eu agradeço.

Comment: implemente um `MLLP` fica muito mais simples

Comment: @RovannLinhalis nuca ouvi falar dele. Vou dar uma pesquisada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como dito nos comentários pelo @Leandro o servidor vai continuar a escrever a mensagem enquanto não houver cancelamento. Achei estranho não haver um exemplo simples como um servidor *echo* no `Github` por isso eu fiz o meu.

### Servidor

```
static async Task Run()
{
    var listenPort = 11000;
    var listener = new TcpSocketListener();
    listener.ConnectionReceived += async (sender, args) =>
    {
        var client = args.SocketClient;
        var reader = new StreamReader(client.ReadStream);
        var data = await reader.ReadLineAsync() + "\n";
        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
        await client.WriteStream.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        await client.WriteStream.FlushAsync();
    };

    await listener.StartListeningAsync(listenPort);
}
```

### Cliente

```
static async Task Run()
{
    var address = "127.0.0.1";
    var port = 11000;

    var client = new TcpSocketClient();
    await client.ConnectAsync(address, port);

    var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Olá mundo\n");
    await client.WriteStream.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    await client.WriteStream.FlushAsync();

    var reader = new StreamReader(client.ReadStream);
    var data = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(data);
}
```

Neste caso o cliente envia uma mensagem para o servidor, o servidor envia a mensagem de volta. O cliente mostra a mensagem na consola e desconecta-se.

Uma observação importante a fazer é que eu optei por usar o `ReadLineAsync` do `StreamReader`. O que isto quer dizer é que quer as mensagens enviadas pelo servidor, quer as mensagens enviadas pelo cliente, tem que terminar em `\n`.

Espero que este seja um exemplo mais útil para os seus objectivos dos que já encontrou.

Comment: Dois códigos tão simples assim ? Ela funciona perfeitamente. Não sei como agradecer !

Comment: Só uma dúvida, que está fora da minha pergunta, É possível fazer o cliente mandar 1 parâmetro para servidor e servidor mandar 3 parâmetros para cliente. É possível isso ? Tipo, uma para string, int e DateTime.

Comment: @MatheusMiranda Básicamente o que voce que fazer é implementar o seu protocolo? Mais um pouco e voce está usando `http`. Pode usar `SignalR`? Ele é básicamente websockets com uma API simples de usar. Há situacoes onde voce usa `TCP` caso queira fazer o seu protocolo. Mas se aquilo que voce quer fazer é uma apicacao, mais vale apena usar algo que exista.

Comment: Bruno , eu não conheço muito bem o `websockets`, porque a ideia é você pegar os dados que tem no "Winforms" e passar para "Xamarin android". Não sei se o `websockets` pode fazer isso.

Comment: ***Básicamente o que voce que fazer é implementar o seu protocolo?*** Sim.

Comment: @MatheusMiranda. Mais uma vez, parece que o SignalR faz aquilo que voce quer. Voce deverá dar uma olhada nisso no fim de semana. É bastante usado em ambiente profissional por isso mesmo que nao vá usar sempre ficará com conhecimento para o futuro.

Comment: Ok, vou dar uma pesquisada.

Comment: Bruno, é possível fazer comunicação usando a senha ? To pensando fazer isso. O servidor cria a senha aleatória com seu ip único e cliente se conecta com endereço ip e a senha.

Comment: @MatheusMiranda Básicamente voce quer um sistema de autenticacao. É possivel fazer sim.

Comment: Bruno, no seu código, as vezes eu recebo uma exceção: Unable to read data from the transport connection: Connection reset by peer. Porque ?

Comment: @MatheusMiranda Peco desculpa nao ter respondido a sua pergunta mas parece que já colocou outra pergunta sobre o assunto.