# Unable to read data from the transport connection: Connection reset by peer

Tags: c#, socket, tcpclient

Segue o código: [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/283564/54019).

O código do cliente está recebendo uma exceção:

> Unable to read data from the transport connection: Connection reset by
>   peer.

Porque esse erro ? E como posso corrigir ?

Answer (score 1):

Aqui vai uma tentativa de traduzir algumas partes da resposta do [David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/60682/david) que me parecem mais interessantes para o seu caso...

Esse erro normalmente significa que o servidor está rodando, mas o serviço que você está tentando conectar não está disponível. (Pode ser que esteja parado, parou de funcionar, ou esteja ocupado com outra requisição)

...É possível que isso esteja sendo causado por uma porta bloqueado no firewall...

O restante da resposta dele parece ser mais voltada para a pergunta específica que fizeram [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420656/unable-to-read-data-from-the-transport-connection-an-existing-connection-was-f) (em inglês).

Espero que ajude.

Comment: @MatheusMiranda, posso estar enganado, mas se não me engano, quando você usa conexão TCP diretamente, você precisa tratar algumas coisas que você não precisaria se estivesse usando um protocolo como HTTP/FTP ou uma biblioteca pronta como o SignalR, por exemplo. No caso do FTP, eu sei que o cliente se conecta ao servidor pela porta 21 e o servidor devolve ao cliente uma nova porta para que ele se conecte para realizar a transferência dos arquivos, liberando assim a porta 21 para que outro cliente possa se conectar. (continua)

Comment: Basicamente, o que quero dizer é que no primeiro click você está conectando no seu servidor pela porta 11000 e se mantendo conectado até terminar a requisição, quando vem o segundo click do botão, ele tenta se conectar na porta 11000 mas ela está ocupada pela primeira requisição e então você recebe a mensagem de erro. Para corrigir isso você teria que tratar isso. O jeito mais comum é usar a porta 11000 apenas como uma porta de entrada, onde a primeira comunicação seja dar ao cliente uma nova porta para que ele se conecte por tempo indeterminado, liberando a porta 11000 logo em seguida.

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui nessa imagem http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/diagrams/ftppassive.png, ela mostra como funciona o protocolo FTP